# Cannot bind to root of domain using LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to connect to the root of our domain to run LDAP Queries but for some reason it keeps failing when I remove the OU from the DN

```
$ldapConnect=ldap_connect("some.domain.com");
if ($ldapConnect)
{
    $ldapBind=ldap_bind($ldapConnect, "aUserName", "aPassword");
    $sr=ldap_search(
        $ldapConnect,
        "DC=some,DC=domain,DC=com",
        "(&(objectCategory=computer (|(operatingSystem=Windows Server*)(operatingSystem=Windows 2000 Server)))"
    );
}
```

The above code fails. If I change the bind to the below, it will work flawlessly:

```
$sr=ldap_search(
    $ldapConnect,
    "OU=anOrgUnit,DC=some,DC=domain,DC=com",
    "(&(objectCategory=computer (|(operatingSystem=Windows Server*)(operatingSystem=Windows 2000 Server)))"
);
```

Anyone have any insight on what is happening here?? `ldap_error()` simply returns `Operations error`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an LDAP option before you do your search like:

```php
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
```

You need to set the `LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS` on Windows domains >= 2003 when trying to search from the domain root.

source:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php